# Add values to two tables through inner join?

Tags: sql

I have two tables **"tbPerson"** and **"tbClient".**

**"tbPerson"** columns: **personid, personname**

**"tbClient"** columns: **clientid, personid**

As you can see **"tbClient"** has **"personid"** as **foreign key** and when I am going to insert the data into **"tbPerson"** I want to save that data in **"tbClient" personid column.**

Summary:
**Save data into tbPerson -> takes personid and save it into tbClient**

```
INSERT INTO `tbclient`( `personid`)
    SELECT `personid` 
    FROM `tbperson`
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT  tbclient.personid FROM `tbclient`WHERE `tbclient`.`clienteid` = `tbperson`.`personid`)
```

This is my code.
Can you help me?

Comment: help you with what? I see no attempt...

Comment: And what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

After the first insert use `mysqli_insert_id($con);` where $con is your DB connection, to get the last inserted id. Then run another insert into the other Table with the new insert id  variable.